# Two questions about Remoting

Tags: c#, remoting

【Question1】

When in the Client-Activation mode for Remoting:

```
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterActivatedClientType(               
                typeof(ServerRemoteObject.ServerObject),
                "tcp://localhost:8080/ServiceMessage");
 ServerRemoteObject.ServerObject serverObj = new ServerRemoteObject.ServerObject();
```

Suppose "ServiceRemoteObject" is a class inherited from MarshalByRefObject and it has a default public constructor, and it's referred by the client side application.

So if I say:

```
 ServerRemoteObject.ServerObject serverObj = new ServerRemoteObject.ServerObject();
```

How does the client application know **whether I'm creating the serverObj instance through the Remoting, not directly creating that instance by "new" locally?**

【Question 2】

I don't want to refer the ServerRemoteObject from the server side, so I just tricked the server side by creating the same class at the client side:

```
public class ServerObject:MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public ServerObj()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Person GetPersonInfo(string name,string sex,int age)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }       
    }
```

This also works fine, why? Because in my mind, the server-side class's namespaces... aren't the same as the client one, which means I've cheated the server-side. But How it can be converted?

Comment: You may want to consider WCF instead of remoting - WCF replaced remoting a long time ago. WCF can be a pain in the neck to configure and work with, but IMO remoting is worse.

Comment: @JoeEnos：Haha……But I really wanna know why? How is it implemented.... Thanks;)